# Where I run mysqldump or pg_dump, Both services (mysql or postgres) freeze?

Tags: mysql, pg-dump

I need to create a database without stopping the services and I don't know this answer.

I need my web pages to continue working properly in that time.

Can someone answer me?

Comment: Also, consider `xtrabackup` and `mariabackup`

Answer (score 1):

MySQL answer because I don't know `pg_dump`.

To allow SQL to continue with mysql during a mysql dump the following is required:

- Tables needs to be innodb. Check with `show create table {tablename}`, change with `alter table {tablename} Engine=innodb` if it isn't (will cause the table to be unavailable during the change).
- Use `mysqldump` with `--single-transaction --master-data=2`. Single transaction is the main point to get a consistent snapshot. `--master-data` enables a point in time recovery if you have binary logs enabled.

The transactional dump will enable the website to continue to read and update date while the mysqldump is occurring. The data in the mysqldump will be the data on the server at the point the backup began.

Note you cannot modify tables during a mysqldump. In MySQL table structure changes aren't transactional.

Answer (score 0):

I'll speak to `pg_dump`. `pg_dump` behaves no differently than other clients, it just happens to query the system catalog tables so it can generate DDL statements, and then will query the regular tables being backed up in order to dump the data. While it may introduce system load due to the i/o of reading the table data, it will not cause normal web application traffic to hang due to locks/etc.

To quote [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) (emphasis mine):

> It makes consistent backups even if the database is being used concurrently. pg_dump **does not block other users accessing the database (readers or writers)**.